# How to set WindowsSafeSearchSetting to Off?

Tags: windows-10, powershell, permissions, windows-search

When I execute `Get-WindowsSearchSetting` in PowerShell, it tells me that `WindowsSafeSearchSetting` is set to `Strict`.

I want to change that setting to `Off`, but when I execute `Set-WindowsSearchSetting -SafeSearchSetting "Off"`, I get this error:

```
WindowsSafeSearchSetting: Can't choose this setting. 
It's been set by Family Safety.
```

I'm using an Admin PowerShell console, and I don't have any "Family Safety" settings turned on (afaik that's a microsoft account thing, where you can register your account as part of a family, I haven't done that).

Comment: Might be buggy. After setting `Set-WindowsSearchSetting -EnableWebResultsSetting $false` and then trying to set `Set-WindowsSearchSetting -SafeSearchSetting Off`, the error message will change. Will it help, if you disable it?

Comment: @Thomas If I set EnableWebResultsSetting to false, and then try to set SafeSearchSetting to Off, it gives me an error telling me that I can't choose this setting because EnableWebResultsSetting is false. So, no it didn't help.

Comment: That's what I meant. And to be precise, it does not say `EnableWebResultsSetting` is set to `false`, but `EnWebResultsSetting`. What makes it look even buggier. But does SafeSearch still work, when WebResults are disabled? (That was my actual question)

Comment: @Thomas Oh, sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, Safe Search is still filtering results even after setting EnableWebResultsSetting to false.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell seems to have problems with this setting, and "fixing" it may require
modifying permissions on sensitive Windows folders, so to be avoided.

Below are two other methods for setting the SafeSearch Filter in Windows 10:

**Method 1 : The Settings app**

- Open Windows Settings
- Click on the Search icon
- Click on "Permissions & History" on the left side
- You can now below "SafeSearch" select between Strict, Moderate or Off.

**Method 2 : Registry update**

To turn Off, copy the following text into a `.reg` file and execute it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SearchSettings]
"SafeSearchMode"=dword:00000000
```

To set to Moderate, set the value of `SafeSearchMode` to `00000001`,
or for Strict set to `00000002`.

This registry update method can also be done in PowerShell, if required.

Comment: This doesn't help, I already had Safe Search set to Off in Windows Settings at Permissions & History. And also already had that registry key set to 0. Windows Search doesn't respect those and still filters the results.
I don't mind modifying permissions on sensitive Windows folders if it is the only way to fix it.

Comment: Do you have Family Safety enabled?

Comment: I couldn't find any "Family Safety" options inside Windows, by doing a google search I found that family safety is a Microsoft program where you can register microsoft accounts linked to windows as part of a family to set some parental controls and things like that. But as I already stated at the end of my question, I'm not part of said program. I'm using a local account on windows, not a microsoft one, I don't think I could even be part of the program unless I linked my windows account to a microsoft account.

Comment: Yes, this shouldn't happen with Windows account, so perhaps the error message is misleading. Try this: [Boot in Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12376/windows-10-start-your-pc-in-safe-mode), disable SafeSearch and reboot *in Safe mode*. Does the setting stick? If it has stuck, try a normal reboot.

Comment: Safe mode didn't work, I got exactly the same results as before, either through the Windows Settings, the Registry, and PowerShell.

Comment: The conclusion is then that this is not caused by an installed third-party product, but is rather a problem in Windows itself. I don't know if the problem is worth a [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). A workaround would be (1) Redo the registry update every time, perhaps setting it to run automatically after login, (2) Use another search engine that doesn't support safe search. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I don't understand (1), redo what registry update? About (2), I don't know of a way to change the default windows search engine (Bing), can it be done without third-party software running on the background?

Comment: Questions: (A) Does disabling Safe Search work immediately after the above manipulations are done? (B) Some third-party software is much better than Windows Search and uses much less resources. I use this and I disabled Windows Search for efficiency. But it's your decision.

Comment: (A) There are no manipulations to do, as I stated in the first comment, the Windows Settings GUI Safe Search option is already Off, and that Registry key is already set to 0, but Windows Search seems to ignore those and still filters the results. 
(B) I'm not interested in installing more software.

Comment: If nothing works then this mechanism in Windows is broken, so none of the known solutions works at all, not even once. In that case, the only way to restore malfunctioning components to a consistent state is by doing [Repair Install with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is exactly the same as doing a Windows upgrade, even if it upgrades Windows only to itself. Take the same precautions and backups as before Windows upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

it's set at admin level from an online account in control of safesearch settings- cannot be done from your computer- just either have a word with the landlord or just get internet from your mobile phone using hotspot - for your PC

Comment: Can you elaborate? I have no landlord, I own my house, and I have full admin access to everything, my computer, my router, any related accounts, etc. What is this online account that is in control of the setting and where do I go to change it?